# Error message when querying the datastore

Tags: java, eclipse, information-retrieval, datastore

I am new to Java, Eclipse, Google App Engine and the Datastore and am writing my first app to teach myself some new technology both for work and for professional development purposes.

I have a Java app that successfully saves and retrieves data from a datastore that I have created based upon the key. I now want to be able to do more general queries based upon other information in my datastore for meta-code such as:

```
select key_column from my datastore where other_column = "data to be searched"
```

To achieve this, I have done some on-line reading and referenced the O'Reilly book *Programming Google App Engine*. I started with the sample code and it fails with the error message:

> An error occured while attempting to contact the server.
>   Please check your network connect and try again

My code at this point is:

```
Query q = new Query("Force");
q.addFilter("ForceName", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, input);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
for (Entity forceresult : pq.asQueryResultIterable()); {
   String newinput = (String) result.getProperty("ForceCode");
}
```

The error occurs on the last `String netinput` line.

The datastore code exists and is good - I have successfully written/read from it.

The documentation on the above sample code is lacking however to a newbie in this area, for instance: I am assuming that the Entity 'forceresult' only exists within the for loop and cannot be referenced from outside it - that is fine with me.

However, in the `String newinput` line, I have coded `result.getProperty` even though it seems to me that it should be `forceresult.getProperty` as this is what I want to refer to.
When I code that however, Eclipse tells me that it cannot resolve `forceresult` even though an `Entity` has been defined in the line above.

Is `result` a reserved word that I missed the significance of?
Is my code wrong in any other respect? Perhaps I am not understanding `asQueryResultIterable` properly yet?
How should I interpret the error message:

> An error occured while attempting to contact the server.
>   Please check your network connect and try again

I hope someone can point me in the right direction either with a specific answer or advice on where to go next in my learning curve.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your loop (a `;` too much :)). Try this:

```
for (Entity forceresult : pq.asQueryResultIterable()) {
//                                                   ^ ; was here
  String newinput = (String) result.getProperty("ForceCode");
}
```

Thus your loop was actually empty and the `result.getProperty(...)` got called outside, where `forceresult` isn't defined.

Comment: Thank-you - what a star you are!